# How to get data from @ManyToMany?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, relation

I have a relation `@ManyToMany` in my `UserEntity`:

```
  @ManyToMany(
    () => Order,
    orders=> orders.users,
  )
  orders?: Order[];
```

how can i get data from this table in one query?

i try this:

```
        const user = await this.conn
            .getRepository(UserEntity)
            .createQueryBuilder('user')
            .addSelect('firstName')
            .addSelect('lastName')
            .leftJoin('user.order', 'order', 'order.id = user.id')
            .getRawMany();
```

but after launch this my console throw me:

```
[Nest] 1262   - 07/20/2020, 12:47:41 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous +1670ms
QueryFailedError: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Do you think that one order will be owned by many users? For many to many, you should breakdown and create a relation table e.g: OrderUserRelation: id, user_id, order_id

Comment: https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations